# How to open a game executable from a **dialog** using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, executable

Can someone please tell me how to open an executable with my vb.net project. For now I have the code for the user selecting the executable from a dialog:

```
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Executable Files|*.exe"
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Select an Executable File"

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.Cursor = New Cursor(openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
    End If
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click a button --> Launch a \*.exe file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631223/click-a-button-launch-a-exe-file)

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific here. »Opening an executable« usually means executing it, which you can do with `Process.Start`. However,  your code looks like you're trying to use the executable as your mouse pointer (?). Since executables are not cursor files this is unlikely to work out well. They may have cursors (or icons, which are similar, but lack the hotspot) _embedded_ into the executable, which you could use, but then you're asking about extracting a resource from an executable and using that as a cursor.

Comment: Yeah what I wanted to do was after having the executable opened, have its icon replace the current icon of the picturebox which is what was used to open the dialog

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to extract an icon from an executable. You can then use its `ToBitmap` method to convert it into a bitmap that you can either assign to your PictureBox' `Image` property, or draw it using a graphics context.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I should use this, I've tried to use this command line but I'm always getting different errors.

Comment: `Icon` is a .NET class with a method `ExtractAssociatedIcon`. This has nothing to do with the command line, it's simply code you can write in VB.NET in your application.